# Fire dynamic custom event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm working on an JSON/AJAX implementation in my Symfony2 project. Everything works  (modals, redirects, etc.) but my "fire event" implementation isn't.

This is my code:

```
$(document).trigger(data.content, [data.data]);
```

The `data.content` contains the name of the event, in this case "lesson_editor.added_step" and the `data.data` contains a HTML string.

I get this error in the jQuery library:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

With the Chrome debugger the above trigger is the line which causes it.

If I replace the `data.content` with the string `"my.test"` it works.

Full JSON string:

```
{"type":"event","content":"lesson_editor_added_step","data":"\n    <div class=\"panel\">\n        <div class=\"panel-heading\">\n            <span class=\"panel-title\">\n                <a data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#steps\" href=\"#step25\">\n                    asdfasdfasdf\n                <\/a>\n            <\/span>\n            <div class=\"pull-right\">\n                <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-success\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Add action\">\n                    <i class=\"fa fa-plus\"><\/i>\n                <\/a>\n                <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-warning\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Edit step\">\n                    <i class=\"fa fa-edit\"><\/i>\n                <\/a>\n                <a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Delete step\">\n                    <i class=\"fa fa-times\"><\/i>\n                <\/a>\n            <\/div>\n        <\/div>\n        <div id=\"step25\" class=\"panel-collapse collapse in\">\n            <div class=\"panel-body\" id=\"actions25\">\n                            <\/div>\n        <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n","flashBag":{"success":["Step added"]}}
```

AJAX Call

```
 the URL
 $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: type,
     data: data,
     beforeSend: this.options.beforeSendCallback
 })
.done($.proxy(function(data) {
    if (data.type === undefined) {
        alert("Ajax data invalid");
        return false;
    }
    // Switch data type
    switch (data.type) {
        case 'modal':
            // Create modal
            $(document).bootstrapModal("createModal", data.content);
            break;
        case 'redirect':
            // Redirect to page
            window.location.replace(data.content);
            break;
        case 'event':
            // Fire a custom event
            $(document).trigger(data.content, [data.data]);
            break;
    }
    // Check if flashbag exists
    if (data.flashBag) {
        $.each(data.flashBag, function(type, messages) {
            $.each(messages, function(index, message) {
                new PNotify({
                    type: type,
                    text: message
                });
            });
        });
    }
    // Fire event
    $(document).trigger('ajax_done', [data.data]);
}), this)
.fail(this.options.failCallback);
```

Comment: I believe you need to provide the elements for which to trigger the event: $("div").trigger... http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I'm not getting it, how are you able to trigger without selecting an element?

Comment: `$(document).trigger(data.content, data.data);` isn't working either

Comment: `lesson_editor.added_step`? What the heck is that? If it's not an Event that already exists, like `click` or a `jQuery.Event` that won't work. Also, you have `$.event.trigger()`. It's like `@Esa` said: `$('#selector').trigger();`.

Comment: can you show us **exactly** what is the content of this `data` variable ? And show us also how you listen to your event, and any other related code

Comment: I have found the issue... It's the "." in the string which isn't accepted. If I use a "_" instead everything is working fine
EDIT: It isn't ... :-(

Comment: I have added some more info in the question

Answer (score 2):

Its best to fire the custom event if its dynamic with:

```
$(document).trigger(data.content, data.data);
```

and catch it with an .on event handler:

```
$(document).on(data.content, function(event, args...) {
   // do something beneficial for your career here
});
```

Comment: `$(document).trigger(data.content, data.data);` isn't working either

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/x4zf9h5L/ You have something else that is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried catching `data.content` event with `$(document).on(data.content, function() {});` ? If you tried it and it doesn't work, which error message do you see on the console?